# Get all nodes where date field matches month and year

Tags: entities, database, datetime

I have a content type with a date field (*myFieldDate*) whose values are timestamps. (I'm collecting only day, month, and year.)

I have a custom form where I have a select list to select month and year. 
I need to use the `EntityFieldQuery` class to get all the nodes where the date field contains the month and the year I specified.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'horas')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_day', 'value', $myFieldDate, '=');
```

If the select list contains `'2015-05'`, for example, the query should return all nodes where *myFieldDate* contains a date for that month and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a range like condition:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'horas')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_day', 'value', $myFieldDate . '-01', '>=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_day', 'value', $myFieldDate . '-31', '<=');
```